# Get decimal value from webpage with C#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, web

There are many threads similar to this one, but I couldn't figure out what I wanted.I want to get decimal value from webpage.

This is the website: https://www.lme.com/Metals/Non-ferrous/LME-Aluminium#Trading+day+summary

I will get the aluminum price that I marked in the picture below.
[image]

I tried the code stated below but it gets only html codes.

```
 WebClient wb = new WebClient();
 String strPageCode = wb.DownloadString("https://www.lme.com/Metals/Non-ferrous/LME-Aluminium#Trading+day+summary");
 richTextBox1.Text = strPageCode;
```

I think I have to inspect page element similar google chrome. For this i tried to selenium nuget package but i couldn't figure out.

Another solution is sendkey CTRL + A and CTRL + C to copy all page contents. Then extract value from clipboard content. But how can i sendkey without openning browser?

Comment: Don't use `WebClient`. And use a library like AngleSharp to process HTML: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

Comment: @Dai Thanx for attention. I have installed nuget package but it gave me error about compatible with NETframework v4.5. Is there any similar nuget package?

Comment: Why on earth are you targeting .NET 4.5?

Comment: @Dai. Actually this version of Net Framework selected by default. I didn't especially choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to grab these values you have to make a `GET` request to this API endpoint: `/api/trading-data/day-delayed?datasourceId=1a0ef0b6-3ee6-4e44-a415-7a313d5bd771`
(Base address: https://www.lme.com).

An example for getting these values:

```
using System.Text.Json;

HttpClient client = new();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.lme.com");
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/trading-data/day-delayed?datasourceId=1a0ef0b6-3ee6-4e44-a415-7a313d5bd771");

var table = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Table>(response);
var bids = table.Rows.Select(r => r.Values[0]);
var offers = table.Rows.Select(r => r.Values[1]);
```

```
// POCO
public class Table
{
    public Row[] Rows { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Strapline { get; set; }
    public string SupportingCopy { get; set; }
    public string NoDataMessage { get; set; }
    public int DataType { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfData { get; set; }
    public DateTime LookbackDate { get; set; }
    public bool HistoricalDataLookbackEnabled { get; set; }
    public int HistoricalDataLookbackRange { get; set; }
    public int HistoricalDataLookbackUnit { get; set; }
    public int HistoricalDataDisplayPeriod { get; set; }
    public string[] ColumnTitles { get; set; }
    public bool HideColumnTitles { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public DateTime BusinessDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Ric { get; set; }
    public string RowTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] BusinessDates { get; set; }
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
    public string HoverMessage { get; set; }
    public string HoverValue { get; set; }
    public object HoverValues { get; set; }
    public string HoverText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much man. It is perfectly worked. But how could you get API endpoints or datasource id?

Comment: On target page just hit `F12` in keyboard to see the devtools and inspect from network tab the `fetch/xhr`. There you can see all calls to API. (Don't forget to reload the page `Ctrl+R`)

Comment: I tried but there is nothing about api endpoint. Please see pic . [link](https://ibb.co/T8WmTR7)

Comment: Reload the page with `Ctrl+R`